# Java Quiz classes issue

Tags: java, android

I am new with Java. I am trying to create a project Quiz. 
My Main class, makes user to choose between 4 categories. He has to enter a number.

```
public class Quizeto {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1. Αθλητικά\t 2. Μουσική\n3. Ταινίες\t 4. Διάφορα\n");
        System.out.println("Διάλεξε κατηγορία: ");
```

After he enters his choice and then I call if statement.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = reader.nextInt();
        if (n==1) {
```

And now, I saw a guy making java android game, he created a new class with the questions. I did the same thing here about each category. How I can write the code, so if the user types "1" the "Αθλητικα" class opens? I know I can just type each question and with "if statement" to check if the option is correct or not, but I want to know if I can do this, with class function. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think, without knowing your exact requirements, my design would either just use methods for organization within a single class, or I would develop a `Catogory` class and use four instances of this class for the four categories in the quiz.

Comment: use a switch statement on your "n" value, case(1):  { new Αθλητικα() }.. etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the java.lang.Class class. For examplet the following outputs 'foo':

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Class clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
    String str = (String) clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("foo");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Nah, I don’t think this is exactly what the asker craves.